# Wearing a hat only works if you click "Wear hat only on this site"

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2020

I cannot wear a hat unless I've checked the "Wear only on this site" box; if I don't check it, it gives this error:

[image]

Can we fix that, please, so it'll wear it network-wide?

Comment: I had this problem, but after trying a different hat and refreshing the page, the problem resolved itself. I never had to turn on "Wear hat only on this site".

Comment: Yes, switch hats and wear it (if that one will apply); wait 10 seconds, switch to the one you want to wear everywhere, adjust it, apply it. Should work then.

Comment: @ollie How about now?

Comment: @AdamLear Yep, great.  Thanks!